# Teradata SQL Optimization

Tags: sql, query-optimization, teradata

I hope this is concise. I am basically looking for a methodology on how to improve queries after watching one of my colleagues speed up my query almost 10 fold with a quick change

I had a query that had two tables `t_item` and `t_action`
`t_item` is basically an item with characteristics and `t_action` is the events or actions that are performed on this item with a time stamp for each action each action also has an id

My query joined the two tables on id. There were also some criteria made on `t_action.action_type` which is free text

My simplified original query was like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_item
  JOIN t_action
  ON t_item.pk = t_action.fk
WHERE t_action.action_type LIKE ('%PURCHASE%')
AND t_item.location = 'DE'
```

This ran OK, it came back in roughly 8 mins

My colleague changed it so that the `t_action.action_type` ended up in the FROM portion of the SQL. This reduced the time to 2 mins

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_item
  JOIN t_action
  ON t_item.pk = t_action.fk
  t_action.action_type LIKE ('%PURCHASE%')
WHERE t_item.location = 'DE'
```

My question is, **Generally, how do you know when to put limits in the FROM clause vs in the WHERE clause.**

I thought that Teradata SQL optimizer does this automatically

Thank you for your help

Comment: When timing queries you need to run them multiple times because they are often much faster the second time due to caching considerations.  Alternatively, you can use hints to clear the cache each time.  You need to look at the explain plan to see if the queries plans are different.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, do you have a document somewhere that explains the explain plan to a novice. I can run it several times and have a look. Considering this is a report that is scheduled to run on a daily basis, does this mean Teradata will be quicker after the initial run?

Comment: @JohnSmith ..http://www.dwhpro.com/teradata-explain/ here is some pointers to understand the the explain of teradata apart from its mannual.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a different plan for conditions in `WHERE` vs. `ON` (unless it's an Outer Join, but this would return different results). The main reason for different run times is system load, the same query will be much slower when the system is running at 100%. Check Explain for both queries, if they're actually different this might be a bug...

Comment: @Dnoeth ...you are correct as i have executed almost same set queries below and got same execution plan for both ..It must be load on the system which affects the performance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't actually need to understand the plan. You just need to see if the two plans are the same. Teradata has a pretty good optimizer, so I would not expect there to be a difference between the two version (could be, but I would be surprised). Hence, caching is a possibility for explaining the difference in performance.

For this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_item JOIN
     t_action
     ON t_item.pk = t_action.fk
        t_action.action_type LIKE '%PURCHASE%'
WHERE t_item.location = 'DE';
```

The best indexes are probably on `t_item(location, pk)` and `t_action(action_type)`. However, you should try to get rid of the wildcards for a production query. This makes the query harder to optimize, which in turn might have a large impact on performance.

Comment: I managed to get a bit of feedback and they told me the reason it was quicker was  the clause was moved after the FROM clause as it is 2nd key drive table to further quality the condition. In the  t_action, action_type is an Index Key and therefore it is filtered as the 1st condition instead.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . It sounds like someone told you that the `where` clause is processed after the `on` conditions.  That would surprise me, because good optimizers should consider both possibilities (I am not very familiar with the Teradaa optimizer, however).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create similar query but didn't see any difference in the explain plan..though record counts were less trans(15k) and accounts(10k) with indexes on Account_number. Probably what Gordon has specified , try to run the query at different time and also check explain plan for both the queries to see any difference.

```
Explain select * from trans t
inner join 
ap.accounts a
on t.account_number = a.account_number
where  t.trans_id like '%DEP%';


  4) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from ap.a by way of a RowHash match
     scan with no residual conditions, which is joined to ap.t by way
     of a RowHash match scan with a condition of ("ap.t.Trans_ID LIKE
     '%DEP%'").  ap.a and ap.t are joined using a merge join, with a
     join condition of ("ap.t.Account_Number = ap.a.Account_Number").
     The result goes into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally
     on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with no confidence
     to be 11,996 rows (1,511,496 bytes).  The estimated time for this
     step is 0.25 seconds.
  -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.25 seconds.


Explain select * from trans t
inner join 
ap.accounts a
on t.account_number = a.account_number
and t.trans_id like '%DEP%';


  4) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from ap.a by way of a RowHash match
     scan with no residual conditions, which is joined to ap.t by way
     of a RowHash match scan with a condition of ("ap.t.Trans_ID LIKE
     '%DEP%'").  ap.a and ap.t are joined using a merge join, with a
     join condition of ("ap.t.Account_Number = ap.a.Account_Number").
     The result goes into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally
     on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with no confidence
     to be 11,996 rows (1,511,496 bytes).  The estimated time for this
     step is 0.25 seconds.
  -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.25 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

The general order of query processing on Teradata is :

Where/And + Joins
Aggregate
Having
Olap/Window
Qualify
Sample/Top
Order By
Format

An easy way to remember is WAHOQSOF - as in Wax On, Wax Off :)